# Given a one step transition matrix, find $E[X_n | X_0 = 0 ], $as $n -> \infty $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Or even more generally, how would you find $E[X_n | X_0 = i ], $ as $ n -> \infty $

Given the one-step transition matrix for a markov chain. I can't find anything helpful online.

My first thought is that the given $X_0$ doesn't even matter, because the future state of a markov chain only depends on the current state, not the history.

Comment: $X_n|X_0=0$ will be distributed according to $P^n_{0,i}$.

Comment: @A.S. ummm so... what are the next steps to get to the final answer?